# Como aplicar dois filtros em um campo de pesquisa?

Tags: cakephp

Tenho um campo `nome_email`, onde nele o usuário digita uma string qualquer e eu preciso que seja filtrado tudo que for colocado nesse campo e exibir algo correspondente ao `NOME` ou `EMAIL` do cliente cadastrado.

Alguma idéia de como fazer isso?

### Conforme [Pedro Elsner](http://pedroelsner.com/2012/06/plugin-filter-results-para-cakephp-2-x/):

```
<?php
    $this->FilterResults->addFilters(
        array(
            'OR' => array(
                'filter1' => array(
                    'User.name' => array('operator' => 'LIKE'),
                    'User.active' => array('value' => '1')
                )
                'filter2' => array(
                'User.username' => array('operator' => 'LIKE')
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

*"Vamos alterar nosso exemplo para concatenar os filtros pela regra OR, e, se o filtro1 for informado queremos apenas usuários ativos. Desta vamos obter a condição:"*

```
WHERE ((User.name LIKE '%Pedro%') 
  AND (User.active = 1)) 
   OR (User.username LIKE '%elsner%')
```

**Logo, o que eu preciso seria um `Filtro` cujo a condição retornada seria algo como:**

```
WHERE ((User.name ILIKE '%Pedro%') OR (User.username ILIKE '%Pedro%'))
```

Comment: Não seria melhor você deixar 2 campos separados?

Comment: Talvez, mas eu preciso fazer assim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você estiver utilizando a versão 3.x do CakePHP pode ser feito dessa forma:

```
$user_email = $this->request->data('user_email');

$this->User->find('all', [
    'conditions' => [
        'OR' => [
            'User.name LIKE' => '%'.$user_email.'%',
            'User.email LIKE' => '%'.$user_email.'%',
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

Creio que funcione também na versão 2.x.

### Editado:

*Adicionando conteúdo à resposta:*

Observando sua resposta, tentei aplicar ao filtro, fazendo desta maneira:

```
<?php
    $this->FilterResults->addFilters(
        array(
            'filter1' => array(
                'OR' => array(
                    'User.name' => array(
                        'operator' => 'ILIKE',
                        'value' => array(
                            'before' => '%',
                            'after' => '%'
                        )
                    ),
                    'User.username' => array(
                        'operator' => 'ILIKE',
                        'value' => array(
                            'before' => '%',
                            'after' => '%'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

**Com esse filtro se eu debugar o mesmo, terei a seguinte saída:**

```
debug($this->Filter->getConditions());
die();


saída:
------
array(
    'OR' => array(
        'User.nome ILIKE'  => '%valordigitado%',
        'User.username ILIKE' => '%valordigitado%'
    )
)
```

Então percorro essas condições e verifico se `$chave == 'OR'` que é o resultado do filtro aplicado, então eu atribuo o seu valor à variável do filtro conforme abaixo:

```
$conditions = array();
$filter1 = '';

foreach ($this->Filter->getConditions() as $chave => $valor) {
    if ($chave == 'OR') {
        $filter1 = $valor;
    }
}
```

Após atribuo a uma variável o valor que foi digitado no campo:

```
$nome_username = $this->request->data['filter']['filter1'];
```

Depois verifico se a variável `$filter1` está vazia e aplico a condição para colocar no `Paginator`

```
if (!empty($filter1)) {
    $conditions[] = "(User.nome ILIKE '%$nome_username%' 
                  OR User.username ILIKE '%$nome_username%')";
}
```

E no `Paginator` eu aplico a variável `$conditions` assim:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'fields' => array( XXXXXX ),
    'joins' => array( XXXXXXX ),
    'conditions' => array($conditions)
);
```

Comment: Editado para se aplicar ao que eu realmente precisava, pois sua resposta estava correta, porém não era exatamente o que eu precisava. Mas obrigado Jeferson Assis